# Which super hero costume is this red and black t-shirt based on?

Tags: character-identification, super-hero

I came across this shirt on a webstore, it's supposed to be a superhero but I don't know who it belongs to.

[image: super hero shirt]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have reason to believe it to be Marvel or DC (or a comic-book hero, for that matter)?

Comment: Is this the website you saw it: http://www.marsi-shopik.cz/marsi-shopik/eshop/95-1-Panske-a-klucici-cyklodresy ? It shows this shirt among a number of obvious super hero shirts.

Comment: http://booyakashaa.com/product/caped-crusader-sidekick/ - "Robin / Nightwing"

Answer (score 13):

### Probably Nightwing (New 52)

[Here](http://cornflakepizza.tumblr.com/post/86901835350/coyotetangopratman-robin-t-shirts-concepts) are some t-shirt concepts that show a rather similar logo:

[image]

We can see that the New 52 version of the Nightwing logo is almost a perfect match.

[Here’s](http://www.dccomics.com/characters/nightwing) an image of Nightwing, wearing a costume that’s the same general shape:

[image]

Comment: It's definitely Nightwing, the t-shirt design in the question and the design on the Nightwing New52 t-shirt look almost identical, though the question shirt certainly looks cheaper

Comment: @ANON - If this answers your question, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark below the voting buttons.